# Downloading Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: windows-xp, security

I want to download Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from ubuntu.com website but only have Windows XP as available OS (no antivirus installed).

I notice when I click on the download link I am always redirected to third party mirrors. How secure is it to do the download procedure? I don’t have any other OS (only this old XP and no antivirus program is installed).

Comment: Sorry, but you are using XP and you are worried about the security?! This does not really make any sense. Anyway you can check the authenticity of an ubuntu download vir GPG: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview The tutorial is for Linux but similar tools exist for Windows (not sure if XP is still supported).

Comment: Oh no.. I am not using XP. My PC had HDD issues... I have to replace the HDD and install new OS. The only available installation I have is the XP DVD which I plan to use for fetching Ubuntu image.

Answer (score 0):

The mirrors are secure. After downloading you can check the iso's hash value, that is also present on the download sites.